# Convexity of $f(v) = E[(\sum_i X_i v_i)^k]$ subj. to $\sum_i v_i^2=1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

I'm interested in the function
$$f(v) = E\left[\big(\sum_i X_i v_i\big)^{2k}\right],$$
where $v$ is conditioned to $\|v\|_2=1$, $k\ge1$ is integer, and $X_i$ are iid random variables.

For which random distributions is $f$ maximized when all the weight of $v$ is concentrated on a single coordinate? That is, when $v=[1,0\dots,0]$.

Clearly when $X_i\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ we get $E\left[\big(\sum_i X_i v_i\big)^{2k}\right]=C_k\|v\|^{2k}_2=C_k$ for some constant $C_k$ depending on $k$. Hence for the normal distribution the `layout' of $v$ doesn't matter. On the other hand, if $X_i$ is an $\alpha$-stable distribution, we'd have $E\left[\big(\sum_i X_i v_i\big)^{2k}\right]=C_k\|v\|^{2k}_\alpha$, which is clearly maximized at $v=[1,0\dots,0]$ when $\alpha<2$.

It seems to me that $f(v)$ will be convex for any random distribution that has Gaussian moments or larger. I have checked it for the exponential distribution and chi-squared as well, but I don't know how to prove this in general.

Is $f(v)$ convex for any distribution with $E\left[X^{2k}\right]\ge (2k-1)!!$ (rhs being the $2k$th moment of a standard normal distribution.)

Comment: $f(v_1,...,v_n)$ is convex (for any random variables for which the expectations are finite) over $\mathbb{R}^n$, but not over the domain $\{v:||v||=1\}$.  For example take the convex function $g(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+x_2)^{2k}$. Then $g(1,0)=1 < g(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}^{2k}$.

Comment: In other words, convexity seems to have nothing to do with the problem.  It would also help to clarify how many terms your sum is over (i.e., the dimension of $v$ is what?), and if the square is inside or outside the expectation (I assume inside). That is, does $E(\sum X_i)^2$ mean $E[(\sum X_i)^2]$ or $E[\sum X_i]^2$?

Comment: @Michael Thank you, I've added more brackets to my expectations. Regarding convexity, I do indeed mean convex over the domain. Is there a better way to state this?

Comment: A convex function must have a convex domain.  There is no function that is convex over the domain $\{v: ||v||=1\}$.

Comment: @Michael That's interesting. Is there another property that I should look at instead to get the kind of result I'm referring to?

Comment: You likely want the $X_i$ to have mean zero since if $E[X_i]=m$ we get $f(1,0,0,..,0)=E[X_1^{2k}]$ and $f(1/\sqrt{n}, ..., 1/\sqrt{n})\geq (m\sqrt{n})^{2k}$, which goes to infinity with $n$ whenever $m\neq 0$. It would also help to know whether or not $n=k$.

Comment: @Michael Good point, I didn't even think of $E[X]$ being different from zero. I don't imagine any special relationship between $k$ and the number of variables. Other than both being sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, we can show that $$
g(v) = E\left[(\sum_{i} v_i X_i)^{2k}\right]^{\frac{1}{2k}}$$ is subadditive, homogeneous of degree $1$ over $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (this implies convexity.) Subadditivity comes from Minkowski's inequality which is implying that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
g(v+w) &=& E\left[(\sum_{i} v_i X_i +\sum_{i} w_i X_i)^{2k}\right]^{\frac{1}{2k}}\\&\leq& E\left[(\sum_{i} v_i X_i)^{2k}\right]^{\frac{1}{2k}} + E\left[(\sum_{i} w_i X_i)^{2k}\right]^{\frac{1}{2k}}\\&=&g(v) + g(w).
\end{eqnarray}$$ Homogeneity can be shown easily:
$$
g(tv) = E\left[(\sum_{i} tv_i X_i)^{2k}\right]^{\frac{1}{2k}}=t E\left[(\sum_{i} v_i X_i)^{2k}\right]^{\frac{1}{2k}} = tg(v),\quad\forall t\geq 0.
$$ This proves $$
g(tv + (1-t)w) \leq g(tv) + g((1-t)w) =tg(v) + (1-t)g(w) ,$$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ and $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $g$ is a non-negative convex function, and the map $t\in [0,\infty)\mapsto t^{2k}$ is non-decreasing convex, we have $f(v) = g(v)^{2k}$ is also convex.

Comment: Convexity came without any requirement on $x$! I guess @Michael was right that convexity is not really the property I need, since my variables live on the sphere. I really appreciate the answer, but do you have any ideas how to show that the sum is maximized when $v=[1, 0,\dots]$ as in the question?